# Will there be any Google+ Apps, like on Facebook?

Tags: google-plus

Although I'm sincerely hoping there aren't going to be any Google+ apps similar to things like Farmville on Facebook, I thought I would ask anyway so I can hurry it up and learn how to develop them.

Comment: Sorry didn't mean to get all slipstream on ya there.

Comment: What's the down vote for?  The answer to this question might change in the future.

Comment: That's exactly why it's not a good question.  You're asking us to speculate on what the future holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google+ has an API and here is the link: http://developers.google.com/+/api/

Comment: Updated your answer because the API is available now.  Feel free to update / reword as you see fit.

Comment: Sorry Greg, I just wanted it to be updated to reflect the updates to Google+.